# Freeing a buffer in C that was created in a function

Tags: c

I'm having some problems trying to free a buffer created in a function from outside that function in C. What I'm doing is to create bufA, do some stuff with it, then call a function which creates bufB, whose length is calculated inside that function. Bytes in bufA are then copied to bufB with some additional bytes added, then the function returns. Some further processing is done with bufB back in main(), then both bufA and bufB are freed. The program runs correctly, but throws an error when free(bufB) is called.

For very much simplified code, I have something like this:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

// -----

int main(void) {

  // -----

  BYTE bufA = NULL;
  // Specify lenBufA
  bufA = calloc(lenBufA, 1);
  // Populate bufA with some stuff.
  BYTE bufB = NULL;
  int lenBufB = myFunction(bufA, &bufB);
  // Do something with bufB.
  free(bufA);
  free(bufB); // <=== Throws an error here.
  return 0;
}
```

Then in myFunction() I may have something like this:

```
int myFunction(BYTE* inBuf, BYTE** outBuf) {
  // Initialization.
  // Calculate the length that outBuf will have and put it in outLen.
  *outBuf = (BYTE*)calloc(outLen, 1);
  // Do stuff with outBuf.
  return outLen;
}
```

inBuf is not specified as constant as some bytes may be changed. calloc() rather than malloc() is used in main() and in the function because I want the bytes in both buffers to be initialized to zero, as a few bytes in both are not given values.

I'm using visual Studio 2022 with Windows 10. Somehow the error caused by free(bufB) must be related to the fact that memory is allocated in the function, not in main(). How is this fixed?

Comment: Enable warnings: `BYTE bufA` and `BYTE bufB` in `main` should be `BYTE *bufA` and `BYTE *bufB`

Comment: Your code will not compile cleanly. Please read [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Comment: Also it's an incredibly bad idea to create your own non-standard with stuff like `typedef unsigned char BYTE;`. Stick to standardized types. For example you could use `uint8_t` from `stdint.h` instead.

Comment: Replace the comments with dummy code, and create [mcve], please.

Comment: *"Somehow the error caused by free(bufB) must be related to the fact that memory is allocated in the function, not in main()."* This is unlikely. You probably have some Undefined Behavior in th real code (leading to heap or other memory corruption).

Comment: Post real code, your code does not compile and therefore cannot run.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is incomplete and does not compile.  The main issue appears to be that the type of `bufA` and `bufB` is `BYTE` but should be a pointer `BYTE *`.  Here is working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

int myFunction(const BYTE *inBuf, BYTE **outBuf) {
    int outLen = strlen(inBuf);
    *outBuf = calloc(outLen, 1);
    if(!*outBuf) {
        printf("calloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return outLen;
}

int main(void) {
    BYTE *bufA = NULL;
    int lenBufA = 42;
    bufA = calloc(lenBufA, 1);
    if(!bufA) {
        printf("calloc failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(bufA, !'\0', lenBufA - 1); // heh

    BYTE *bufB = NULL;
    int lenBufB = myFunction(bufA, &bufB);
    free(bufA);
    free(bufB);
    return 0;
}
```

It checks the return code of calloc, clarifies with `const BYTE *inBuf` that function doesn't change that argument.

Comment: I didn't copy and paste correctly, in the original code I have BYTE* bufA = NULL and BYTE* bufB = NULL, and do indeed check if calloc() has worked. But it was getting late, and now it's very late.

Comment: Yes, many thanks, your answer was useful, and I've not seen something like memset(bufA, !'\0', lenBufA - 1 before. However, I'm still stuck with the error when trying to free bufB. As I said, the code works correctly, it's just that I can't free that buffer. Incidentally, the full code is part of a project to convert 7-bit ASCII codes into 6 bits, which limits one to 64 characters. However, by using escape characters, most of the printable characters can be processed, together with 2 control codes NUL and line feed.

Comment: It does not work if you cannot free a buffer.  We need a [mre] to reproduce the issue for you.  I was not able to with the information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

On Googling ntdll.dll, it appears to be a Windows file of some type, and based on some blurb, it might be corrupted.

Accordingly, I copied the source files to another Windows 10 computer that also has Visual Studio 2022 installed, created a project, then compiled the source code. On executing I get the same message with different hex codes, However the hex code for sixbit-encoding6.exe is the same. Unfortunately the copy and paste feature of the mouse doesn't work for the message on that computer, but it thus looks as if the dll is probably not corrupted, and there is a problem with my application.

Comment: OK, I created a minimal project with Visual Studio 2022, and everything worked with the buffers closed without errors. I then returned to my original project and after some further testing discovered that in a loop in the function in question the code was writing beyond the end of the output buffer. No errors were created at that point and the application appeared to work correctly, but failed when I attempted to close the buffer. This has been fixed and the code is now working correctly. The moral is always close buffers in C after you have finished with them, even at the end of a program.